# How to secure AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml

sorry if my speak english is bad and I hope you understand.

My question for How to secure AndroidManifest.xml.

I have Android studio project app and I try build login activity with firebase, because i want user premium only for access the apps. but I have problem, in AndroidManifest.xml can edit with apkEditor or apktools, just edit and remove .Activitylogin and change or replace to .ActivityMain my app can acces without login.

Any idea?

Comment: Manifest is always public. Access to premium features needs to be verified by a server (your or Google Play or another).

Comment: is there a solution to other than google play?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard, a commercial version of ProGuard to obfuscate Android Manifest and xml files. However, there are some classes which can not be obfuscated, i.e some may be referenced from outside.